# Are Bombs (DMG 267) legal in AL play?

Tags: dnd-5e, equipment, dnd-adventurers-league

Are Bombs (DMG 267) legal in AL play?

Also relevant: Are Explosives (DMG 267-268) legal in AL play?

> ## Explosives
>
> A campaign might include explosives from the Renaissance or the modern world (the latter are priceless), as presented in the Explosives table.

Comment: The DMG is not a leagal choice for your +1, however I think the +1 is for character creation, not items acquired later on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Dungeon Master's Guide* does not contain material that players can pick to use in Adventurers League.

It contains a few things that are unlockable through Adventurers League certificates or actual play, but I've yet to see anything that unlocks bombs or explosives.

[Page 2 of the Adventurers League Player's Guide (v8.2)](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/ALPGv82.pdf#page=2) includes a note below Steps 1 & 2 (race/class) of character creation (emphasis mine):

> NOTE: Races with flight at 1st level, and options from any resource other than those listed above (such as the ***Dungeon Master's Guide***, Guild Adept products, or Unearthed Arcana articles) aren’t available without specific campaign documentation (i.e., certs, etc.).